# iOS6 has loaded someone totally different's details

Tags: ios

I did an Over The Air update on my iPhone 4S this morning to IOS6. But it has showed me someone elses phone number after the update.

When I send an iMessage to my wife, it comes from this random persons phone number. When I try to facetime, it comes from this other number. But "Phone" shows the correct phone number:

[image]

^ This is the FaceTime setup. That is *not* my phone number. I have never seen that number in my life before.

[image]

^ This is the Phone set up. That *is* my phone number.

What's going on? How can I change this? Has someone else got my phone number and is getting my wifes messages?

Comment: Too much cloud in these phones. Best of luck, I think that Apple is having problems, or was having them with iCloud last couple of days. I don't know why Apple decided to flakify this service. Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

Sign out, all areas (including Game Center) turn off iCloud an soft reboot, an sign back in

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the number manually.
To do that, navigate to: *Settings* > *Phone* > *My Number*.
It will allow you to change the number from there. See if that helps.

If that doesn't help, try resetting your network settings.
To do that, go to *Settings* > *General* > *Reset* > *Reset Network Settings*.
This will not affect your data nor your apps.

Comment: As you can see from my photos, the settings > phone > my number is already set correctly. I tried the 2nd one but no luck. It's not related to the phone, it's related to FaceTime and iMessage.

Answer (score 0):

Are you signed in with your own apple id? Something like that happened to my bf's sister where she was sending texts/iMessage from HIS number because she was signed into his account for some reason. She signed into her own & it was fixed, but idk if that's your situation.

Comment: No, I only have one apple ID and I was signed in using the correct one.